# Optional Parameters in Python with List Append

Tags: python, optional-parameters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Least Astonishment” in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

This is very odd, an optional list parameter in Python is persistent between function calls when using the .append() method.

```
def wtf(some, thing, fields=[]):
    print fields
    if len(fields) == 0:
        fields.append('hey');
    print some, thing, fields

wtf('some', 'thing')
wtf('some', 'thing')
```

The output:

```
[]
some thing ['hey']
['hey'] # This should not happen unless the fields value was kept
some thing ['hey']
```

Why does the "fields" list contain "hey" when it is a parameter? I know it's local scope because I can't access it outside the function, yet the function remembers its value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default values are only evaluated once, so using a mutable type as a default value will produce unexpected results.  You'd do better to do something like this:

```
def wtf(some, thing, fields = None):
  if fields is None:
    fields = []
```

Comment: Note that this won't save you if you ever call `wtf('some', 'thing', something)`. Now `something` has an extra `"hey"` on the end.

Comment: how so? If "something" were a list, then it would not be None and so the "fields" would equal "something" would it not?